# How to map UV coordinates of a texture to the "inner" UV coordinates of a sub rectangle?

Tags: math, graphics, shader

In a fragment shader I get the UV coordinates of the current pixel in the range of [0.0,1.0]. However, I don't render the whole texture (thus in UV from 0.0 to 1.0), but only a sub rectangle of it. So the UV coordinates I get in this shader are only a sub range of [0.0,1.0], as the other parts are outside the rectangle that I render.

In my shader I do want to work with UV coordinates in the range of [0.0,1.0], but mapped to the sub rectangle of the texture that I render.

So my question is: given the total size of the texture and the sub rectangle of that texture that I render, how can I convert the given UV coordinates for the overall texture to the "inner" UV coordinates of my sub rectangle, but again also in the range [0.0,1.0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I will use GLSL and the GLSL type `vec2` which corresponds to the HLSL type `float2`.

Suppose you have a texture with a size (`vec2 tSize`) and a rectangular area in the texture from `vec2 tMin;` to `vec2 tMax`. You want to map the texture coordinate (`vec2 uv`) in the range [0.0, 1.0] to the rectangular area in the texture. Either do the mapping with an expression using the formula *val * (max - min) + min*:

```c
vec2 uvMapped = (uv * (tMax - tMin) + tMin) / tSize;
```

Or use the GLSL function [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) (GLSL `mix`, corresponds to HLSL [`lerp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-lerp)):

```c
vec2 uvMapped = mix(tMin, tMax, uv) / tSize;
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the idea with the `mix()` function.